# Issue with time command

Tags: linux, centos7

When I run several background jobs, I need to get a runtime for the set of jobs.
I use the following example successfully:

```
$ sleep 10 &
$ time wait
real    0m9.74s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
```

However, if I try to format the output to seconds, I get the following error:

```
$ time -f %e wait
time: cannot run wait: No such file or directory
0.00
```

This only seems to happen with shell builtins. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Try TIMEFORMAT environment

Comment: Typically if you want to time a shell built-in, you can do that by doing something like "time /bin/bash -c 'wait'"  Unfortunately in this case, the wait is waiting on sub-processes associated with the shell it is running in, not the background process you started outside of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is two-fold.

- we don't know if you're using the bash (assuming you're using the centos default shell) built-in or the binary `time` command.
- in either case `wait` is a bash built-in

Ways to deal with this:

```
/usr/bin/time -f %e bash -c wait
TIMEFORMAT="%pR" time bash -c wait
```

Comment: What use is `bash -c wait` here?

Comment: @Narfanar  `wait` is a bash builtin, `time` can't find it in the `PATH` to execute.  See the error message the OP posted.

Comment: But won't that spawn a subshell? Why would it wait for the jobs I started in the parent shell?

Comment: It won't, and I was just trying to explain to him why `time wait` didn't work.